# Connection String of Membership is Problem

Tags: asp.net

Connection String:

```
data source=mssql2008.chaiyohosting.com;Integrated
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Error:

```
Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 20:     protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
Line 21:     {
Line 22:         if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
Line 23:         {
Line 24:             e.Authenticated = true;

Source File: c:\inetpub\vhosts\vcantop.com\httpdocs\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 22
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString.VerifyLocalHostAndFixup(String& host, Boolean enforceLocalHost, Boolean fixup) +811400
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +2207
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +200
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +62
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +24
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +54

[ArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString]
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +136
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +134
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +815
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +42
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +78
   System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +46
   _Default.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\vhosts\vcantop.com\httpdocs\Default.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +166
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

---

What's Wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error seems clear - the value you have for `AttachDBFilename` is invalid.

`|DataDirectory|` should be the physical path to the `.mdf` file:

```
c:\data dir\aspnetdb.mdf
```

All together:

```
data source=mssql2008.chaiyohosting.com;Integrated
Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=c:\data dir\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Comment: On Localhost is fine,but when i'am copy to the real hosting don't work. And how to finds physical path on real hosting.

Comment: @Cake - you will need to ask your hosting company. A relative path may work.